# flutter crashlytics FormatException: Invalid radix-10 number (at character 1)

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I have this error :

```
Fatal Exception: io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FlutterError: FormatException: Invalid radix-10 number (at character 1)
4.
^
. Error thrown null.
```

it point   `temps=  prefs.getString("temps")??"6";`

But I don't know why I have this error, ??"6" force to have temps="6" so it's impossible to have other letter

```
temps=  prefs.getString("temps")??"6";
temps_int= int.parse("$temps");
```

Comment: most likely, you need `int.parse(temps);`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.tryParse`

```dart
temps_int= int.tryParse("${prefs.getString("temps")}")??6;
```